# Don't draw parent content

Tags: unity-game-engine

Let's say I have a text object filled with dots (`............`). Let's also say that I create another text object as a child of the first text object, with the content `foo`.

Between each space in the letters of `foo`, there are clearly visible the dots of the parent. Is there a way I could filter the content of the parent?

Example:

[image]

I'd like to keep the semi-transparent white scroll panel and the hexagon background image, but I'd like to remove the dots behind the numbers `4500`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a Horizontal layout group instead

- Parent (object with only the HorizontalLayoutGroup)

  - Child Object 1 : contains your ....
  - Child Object 2 : Contains your "foo" or numbers

The parent will have the total size of your current parent object (total width)

When setting Child2's text it will resize automatically, which will effectively hide the extra "dots".

No special hacks required

Link to get you started : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-HorizontalLayoutGroup.html

Comment: I tried that, but it's not working as expected. If I add enough dots in the first text object, they will eventually show behind the second text object.

Comment: On the "Text" behavior you can set it to hide the overflowing characters, have you tried that (Horizontal=Wrap and Vertical=Truncate)?
Links : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text-horizontalOverflow.html and  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text-verticalOverflow.html

Comment: There is no such option for horizontal. There is only overflow (which is exactly the opposite of what I want) or wrap, which moves the "extra" dots to a new line.

Comment: As per my previous comment (it was edited) you can set these 2 options, together you will get what you want.

Horizontal=Wrap - 

Vertical=Truncate